# How do I make the frequencies print horizontal rather than vertical?

Tags: python

I have made a code to print the frequencies for the EZEE game for school. I tried to run the code but it printed vertically. I have to take a screenshot and my teacher said it would look more appealing if they printed horizontally rather than vertically. The code is attached. If anyone can fix it and implement it in my code, that would be greatly appreciated.

Code: https://repl.it/Hyye/6

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line

Original

```
for each in results:
    print(each)
```

Alteration

```
print(results)
```